# Firebase email verification android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase development. I am creating a user login system with Firebase. I am struggling with verifying emails registered users. Here is the code I wrote.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.i("Success", "Yes");
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.i("Success", "No");}
                        }
                    });

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

EDIT: No verification email is triggered when sign up is successful. The error I am getting is

> 10-12 10:41:47.579 10529-10529/com.firebase I/Success:
>   Nocom.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has
>   occurred. [ USER_NOT_FOUND ]

Comment: please state the exact nature of the problem you are facing, if possible post the error log as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to Enable Email & Password Authentication, Configuring Email & Password
2. In this [page](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) you can find many tutorials on the page.

If you are using the new version of  firebase, you could try to check  your connection... Info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: if the version is old you can check this page https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html   if the version is new you need check this page  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup   Google, in the new version, google change so many the structure of api, , but the logic is the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the status of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` to ensure that it is successful before getting the current user and calling `sendEmailVerification()`.  There are a number of reasons why `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` might fail (account already exists, weak password, malformed email address, etc.).  When it does fail, the current user with be the previously signed-in user or null, if there has not been a previous sign-in.

Restructure your code like this:

```
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.i("Success", "Yes");
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.i("Success", "No");}
                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```