# Firebase confirmation email isn't sent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            Log.d("user","a user has logged in");    //tried calling sendEmailVerification here
        }
        else{
            Log.d("user","user has logged out");
        }
    }
});
.........
}

public void signUpButtonClick(View view){
//after making sure that the user entered email and password
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mailEntry,passwordEntry).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

    Log.d("task","success");    //tried calling sendEmailVerification here


}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();     

}
});

}
```

Creating a new user works fine, but calling `sendEmailVerification()` has no effect, mail not being sent. Help needed.

- I am using latest version of Firebase SDK
- I checked spam folder to make sure mails not stored there

Comment: Are you testing that the user creation was successful?  For example, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40001296/4815718

Comment: you should check `task.isSuccessful()` in `onComplete`

Comment: Yes the user creation is succesfull. getCurrentUser() isn't null after sign up and I also checked firebase console

Comment: Do you have a completion listener on `sendEmailVerification()`?  Is its returned task successful?

Comment: No I didn't attach a listener for that , let me check